# Can't Find Transaction

Tags: transaction-confirmation, exchange

My question is how do I check if a transaction is in progress.  **I am willing to tip the person who helps me with this $50** (I will PM the person to get their LTC or ETH or XMR address to send to).

I transferred some XMR from Bithumb to Binance at 9am PST today (its currently 1pm). Normally I would be more patient as I could check if the transaction is on the network or block-chain in other crypto-currencies. However I have been unable to verify (possibly due to the anonymity of Monero). The information I have is the:

- Deposit Address (from Binance)
- Payment ID (from Binance)
- Transaction Number (From Bithumb)
- Address (from Bithumb) (note that this is way longer than my deposit address)

With this information, how can I check on my transaction's progress (or if I have lost my money). I have tried putting this information into http://xmr.llcoins.net but i get "Failed to get transaction data! Perhaps MoneroBlocks is down?"
Thank you!

- Could I have used a "wrong address" (note the address and payment ID I used were the ones provided by Binance)
- Could it be that Binance and Bithumb are not compatable (I noticed that my deposit address on Binance is 95 characters and the deposit address on Bithumb is 106 characters)
- Could it just be taking a while (Bithumb says its fee was .05 XMR)

Answer (score 1):

Use the transaction ID/hash/number. It should look something like this:

`c6ad90452a1c62171522484a3d8c8585d6461f544c6c44933850b90f76745895`

Paste yours in a block explorer. I highly suggest [xmrchain.net](https://xmrchain.net).

If it doesn't return anything, the block explorer is down/out of sync (unlikely), or your transaction did not go through. Contact the first exchange (Binance) and ask them to confirm they actually sent your transaction.

Comment: Ok. I checked on xmrchain.net.and there is no result. Is it possible that it just has not gone through yet? i.e. is 4 hours reasonable for a transfer?

Comment: I would definitely contact the exchange if it has been 4 hours already.